# CSS + JS Flex display on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

This problem doesn't happen on Mozilla Firefox but appears on all browsers I have tested (Edge, Google Chrome, Opera)

I have a parent flex display with column orientation.
Inside this parent flex are flex containers of row orientation(there are elements inside as well).

```
.inputManageTableDataRowContainer {
    flex: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 40px;
    visibility: visible;
    align-items: flex-start;
    border-color: var(--dl-color-gray-900);
    border-width: 2px;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: rgba(153,153,153,0.32);
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
}
.inputManageTableDataRowContainer {
    flex: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 40px;
    visibility: visible;
    align-items: flex-start;
    border-color: var(--dl-color-gray-900);
    border-width: 2px;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: rgba(153,153,153,0.32);
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
}
```

Code snippet

```js
for (let x = 1; x <= m_iDefaultNumRows; x++){
    var strInputNumber = x.toString().padStart(4, '0');
    var strTagInputContainer = m_strTagInputHead + strInputNumber + m_strTagRowContainer;
    var strTagInputName = m_strTagInputHead + strInputNumber + m_rowElementsTags.InputName;
    var strInputName = document.getElementById(strTagInputName).textContent; 
    strInputName = strInputName.trimStart();
    strInputName = strInputName.trimEnd();
    if (strInputName.substring(0, searchLen) != strSearchName){
        document.getElementById(strTagInputContainer).style = "min-height: 0px";
        document.getElementById(strTagInputContainer).style = "height: 0px";
        document.getElementById(strTagInputContainer).style = "visibility: collapse";
        //document.getElementById(strTagInputContainer).style = "visibility: hidden";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(strTagInputContainer).style = "visibility: visible";
        document.getElementById(strTagInputContainer).style = "height: 50px";
        document.getElementById(strTagInputContainer).style = "min-height: 40px";
    }
    $(strTagInputContainer).load(sprintf(" %s > *",strTagInputContainer));
}
while(document.readyState != "complete"){
    Delay(1);
}
$(m_strTagDataTableContainer).load(sprintf(" %s > *",m_strTagDataTableContainer));
```

This is for a table as shown in this render image
[Render image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm6j9.png)

I have another box for search option. As I type into that, the idea is to hide child elements on the table.

My problem is the inputManageTableContainer doesn't auto resize when some child elements are hidden or collapse. Also, I expect the shown elements to cascade automatically to top position because position is relative. In the case of problem image, element with name 'EFG' needs to appear on top. Hiding the elements is not an issue as you can see in the problem image.

[image: Problem Render Image]

The correct render I am expecting:

[image: Correct Render Image]

I tried adding a load function for inputManageTableContainer and inputManageTableDataRowContainer , but result is the same.

I know that my element tags or ID for 3 items below are correct since I can change their height manually
-parent container (m_strTagDataTableContainer)
-child container (strTagInputContainer)
-input name (strInputName)

Comment: CCS should be CSS

Comment: Please don't post images of **code**, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: Apologies for the typo and not using of images correctly. Only my second posting in Stack Overflow. Not aware of the rules. Thanks for pointing it out. Anyway, I edited all the contents. Only attaching only render images. Thanks